# D3 JS Displaying Text Next To Circle

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3 and I am trying to modify some sample code.  I can display a geo map, limit it to the US, draw circles for each of the cities I want represented but I can't figure out how to display text next to those circles.  When I inspect the page I can see that D3 has created a child element in the path and it has the name of the city but I can't seem to make it appear.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the code I am working with:

```
    
    .states {
      fill: #ccc;
      stroke: #fff;
    }
    .symbol {
      fill: steelblue;
      fill-opacity: .8;
      stroke: #fff;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    

    var width = 960,
        height = 500;

    var radius = d3.scale.sqrt()
        .domain([0, 1e6])
        .range([0, 10]);

    var path = d3.geo.path();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    queue()
        .defer(d3.json, "us.json")
        .defer(d3.json, "us-state-centroids.json")
        .await(ready);

    function ready(error, us, centroid) {
      svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "states")  
            .datum(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states))
            .attr("d", path);

    var symbols =  svg.selectAll(".symbol")
            .data(centroid.features.sort(function(a, b) { return b.properties.population - a.properties.population; }))
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", "symbol")
            .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
            .on("mouseover", function (b) {
                d3.selectAll('.line_over').style("display", "block");
            })
            .attr("d", path.pointRadius(function(d) { return radius(d.properties.population); }))       

    symbols.append("text")
         .text(function(d){
                        return d.properties.name;
                    })
    }
```

Comment: Don't append the `text` to the `path`, append it to the SVG.

Comment: I tried that and I see where the it creates the text element now within the SVG but it is still not displaying the text. I set the fill and the font-size in a css class and set the class attr but still no go.

Comment: Did you check that the property you're referencing is set?

Comment: I took that out of the equation and just set it to 123.  It is set though because the when I had it appended to the path it was setting the text value to the City name.

Comment: <pre>svg.append("text")
  .text(function(d){
     return "123";
    })
  .attr("class", "text-label") </pre>

Comment: And that appends the text, but not at the right position? You need to set `x` and `y` attributes as well.

Comment: I'll be damned.  good deal!!!  any hints as to how I should go about passing that bound value to set the text?  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: You can do exactly the same thing as you do for the paths, except selecting and appending the `text` elements.

Comment: Awe-Yee-Yeah!!!! Rock solid!!! Thanks!